# Множественное число

Tags: грамотная-речь

Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно "много вешалов" или "много вешал"? Заранее благодарна!
С уважением, Анна

Answer (score 4):

Вешало (ср. род, ед.ч.)  - вешала (мн.ч.) - много вешал (Р.п. мн.ч.) - здесь нулевое окончание, что соответствует основному правилу: если в начальной форме слово имеет ненулевое окончание, то во мн. числе Р.п. это окончание нулевое, например озеро - много озер.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, слово "вешало" какое-то кривое (как по мне, все равно, что "зало" или "стуло")))). Есть русское слово "вешалка", его и склоняйте.

Comment: Русское слово "вешалка" обозначает 1 предмет, а не совокупность - столбов или жердей с поперечными перекладинами